# Infinite CSV file separated by characters rather than new line

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

As you will see in the attached code I have a function containing a `separator` command for `'\n'` Which would lead me to expect the code to separate by every new line. But instead it separated by character. This is particularly strange since it works correctly when I tell it to print what is scraped. Then the loop stops because it reached the end of the class on the website which is what I want and is what I expected. But when I try to put it into a CSV file it starts and the beginning of the list of strings and adds commas between each character rather than each new line and every time it reaches the end of the list it goes to a new line and prints it all over again for infinity. I think Pandas could help a lot here.

I need help getting it to just create one row that is seperated by each new line and stopping the loop once it reaches the end of the list. You can find an example of what I am looking for below.

Here is the code:

```
import re
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = requests.get('https://www.caranddriver.com/reviews/a24847025/2018-ford-mustang-automatic-transmission-performance/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(URL.text, 'html.parser')

#Create a file to write to, add headers row
file = csv.writer(open('CarScrapeTest.csv','w',newline='\n'))
lable=file.writerow(['Name'])

for tag in soup.find_all(class_="specs-content"):
    DataList=tag.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n".replace('"', ""))
for items in DataList:
    file.writerow(DataList)
    
print('DONE!')
```

The list of strings I get when I tell it to print is as follows:

```
Specifications

2018 Ford Mustang EcoBoost Premium Automatic

VEHICLE TYPE:

front engine, rear-wheel-drive, 4-passenger, 2-door coupe

PRICE AS TESTED:

$40,570 (base price: $31,690)

ENGINE TYPE:

turbocharged and intercooled DOHC 16-valve inline-4, aluminum block and head, direct fuel injection

Displacement:

138 cu in, 2261 cc

Power:

310 hp @ 5500 rpm

Torque:

350 lb-ft @ 3000 rpm

TRANSMISSION:

10-speed automatic with manual shifting mode

CHASSIS

Suspension (F/R): struts/multilink

Brakes (F/R): 13.9-in vented disc/13.0-in vented disc

Tires: Michelin Pilot Sport 4S, 255/40ZR-19 (100Y)

DIMENSIONS

Wheelbase: 107.1 in

Length: 188.5 in

Width: 75.4 in

Height: 54.3 in

Passenger volume: 83 cu ft

Trunk volume: 14 cu ft

Curb weight: 3750 lb

C/D

TEST RESULTS

Zero to 60 mph: 5.0 sec

Zero to 100 mph: 13.7 sec

Zero to 130 mph: 26.1 sec

Rolling start, 5–60 mph: 5.6 sec

Top gear, 30–50 mph: 3.1 sec

Top gear, 50–70 mph: 3.8 sec

Standing ¼-mile: 13.5 sec @ 99 mph

Top speed (governor limited,

C/D

est): 150 mph

Braking, 70–0 mph: 153 ft

Roadholding, 300-ft-dia skidpad: 0.98 g

C/D

FUEL ECONOMY

Observed: 20 mpg

EPA FUEL ECONOMY

Combined/city/highway: 23/20/29 mpg

`>>CLICK TO DOWNLOAD TEST SHEET<<

—

2018 Ford Mustang GT Automatic

VEHICLE TYPE:

front engine, rear-wheel-drive, 4-passenger, 2-door coupe

PRICE AS TESTED:

$47,160 (base price: $36,185)

ENGINE TYPE:

DOHC 32-valve V-8, aluminum block and heads, port and direct fuel injection

Displacement:

307 cu in, 5038

Power:

460 hp @ 7000 rpm

Torque:

420 lb-ft @ 4600 rpm

TRANSMISSION:

10-speed automatic with manual shifting mode

CHASSIS

Suspension (F/R): struts/multilink

Brakes (F/R): 15.0-in vented disc/13.0-in vented disc

Tires: Michelin Pilot Sport 4S, F: 255/40ZR-19 (100Y) R: 275/40ZR-19 (105Y)

DIMENSIONS

Wheelbase: 107.1 in

Length: 188.5 in

Width: 75.4 in

Height: 54.3 in

Passenger volume: 83 cu ft

Trunk volume: 14 cu ft

Curb weight: 3851 lb

C/D

TEST RESULTS

Zero to 60 mph: 3.8 sec

Zero to 100 mph: 8.5 sec

Zero to 130 mph: 14.8 sec

Zero to 150 mph: 21.7 sec

Rolling start, 5–60 mph: 4.6 sec

Top gear, 30–50 mph: 2.5 sec

Top gear, 50–70 mph: 2.9 sec

Standing ¼-mile: 12.1 sec @ 120 mph

Top speed (governor limited): 156 mph

Braking, 70–0 mph: 156 ft

Roadholding, 300-ft-dia skidpad: 0.97 g

C/D

FUEL ECONOMY

Observed: 16 mpg

75-mph highway driving: 24 mpg

Highway range: 380 miles

EPA FUEL ECONOMY

Combined/city/highway: 19/16/25 mpg

`>>CLICK TO DOWNLOAD TEST SHEET<<
```

What I want is something like this:

```
Specifications,2018 Ford Mustang EcoBoost Premium Automatic,VEHICLE TYPE:,front engine, rear-wheel-drive, 4-passenger, 2-door coupe,PRICE AS TESTED:,$40,570 (base price: $31,690),ENGINE TYPE:,turbocharged and intercooled DOHC 16-valve inline-4, aluminum block and head, direct fuel injection,Displacement:,138 cu in, 2261 cc,Power:,310 hp @ 5500 rpm,Torque:,350 lb-ft @ 3000 rpm,TRANSMISSION:,10-speed automatic with manual shifting mode,CHASSIS,Suspension (F/R): struts/multilink,Brakes (F/R): 13.9-in vented disc/13.0-in vented disc,Tires: Michelin Pilot Sport 4S, 255/40ZR-19 (100Y),DIMENSIONS,Wheelbase: 107.1 in,Length: 188.5 in,Width: 75.4 in,Height: 54.3 in,Passenger volume: 83 cu ft,Trunk volume: 14 cu ft,Curb weight: 3750 lb,C/D,TEST RESULTS,Zero to 60 mph: 5.0 sec,Zero to 100 mph: 13.7 sec,Zero to 130 mph: 26.1 sec,Rolling start, 5–60 mph: 5.6 sec,Top gear, 30–50 mph: 3.1 sec,Top gear, 50–70 mph: 3.8 sec,Standing ¼-mile: 13.5 sec @ 99 mph,Top speed (governor limited,,C/D,est): 150 mph,Braking, 70–0 mph: 153 ft,Roadholding, 300-ft-dia skidpad: 0.98 g,C/D,FUEL ECONOMY,Observed: 20 mpg,EPA FUEL ECONOMY,Combined/city/highway: 23/20/29 mpg,>>CLICK TO DOWNLOAD TEST SHEET<<,—,2018 Ford Mustang GT Automatic,VEHICLE TYPE:,front engine, rear-wheel-drive, 4-passenger, 2-door coupe,PRICE AS TESTED:,$47,160 (base price: $36,185),ENGINE TYPE:,DOHC 32-valve V-8, aluminum block and heads, port and direct fuel injection,Displacement:,307 cu in, 5038,Power:,460 hp @ 7000 rpm,Torque:,420 lb-ft @ 4600 rpm,TRANSMISSION:,10-speed automatic with manual shifting mode,CHASSIS,Suspension (F/R): struts/multilink,Brakes (F/R): 15.0-in vented disc/13.0-in vented disc,Tires: Michelin Pilot Sport 4S, F: 255/40ZR-19 (100Y) R: 275/40ZR-19 (105Y),DIMENSIONS,Wheelbase: 107.1 in,Length: 188.5 in,Width: 75.4 in,Height: 54.3 in,Passenger volume: 83 cu ft,Trunk volume: 14 cu ft,Curb weight: 3851 lb,C/D,TEST RESULTS,Zero to 60 mph: 3.8 sec,Zero to 100 mph: 8.5 sec,Zero to 130 mph: 14.8 sec,Zero to 150 mph: 21.7 sec,Rolling start, 5–60 mph: 4.6 sec,Top gear, 30–50 mph: 2.5 sec,Top gear, 50–70 mph: 2.9 sec,Standing ¼-mile: 12.1 sec @ 120 mph,Top speed (governor limited): 156 mph,Braking, 70–0 mph: 156 ft,Roadholding, 300-ft-dia skidpad: 0.97 g,C/D,FUEL ECONOMY,Observed: 16 mpg,75-mph highway driving: 24 mpg,Highway range: 380 miles,EPA FUEL ECONOMY,Combined/city/highway: 19/16/25 mpg,>>CLICK TO DOWNLOAD TEST SHEET<<
```

but what I get instead is something more like this:

```
S,p,e,c,i,f,i,c,a,t,i,o,n,s, ,2,0,1,8, ,F,o,r,d, ,M,u,s,t,a,n,g, ,E,c,o,B,o,o,s,t, ,P,r,e,m,i,u,m, ,A,u,t,o,m,a,t,i,c,,V,E,H,I,C,L,E, ,T,Y,P,E,:,,f,r,o,n,t, ,e,n,g,i,n,e, ,r,e,a,r,-,w,h,e,e,l,-,d,r,i,v,e, ,4,-,p,a,s,s,e,n,g,e,r, ,2,-,d,o,o,r, ,c,o,u,p,e,,P,R,I,C,E ,A,S, ,T,E,S,T,E,D,:,,$,4,0,,5,7,0, ,(,b,a,s,e, ,p,r,i,c,e,:, ,$,3,1,,,6,9,0,),,E,N,G,I,N,E ,T,Y,P,E,:,,t,u,r,b,o,c,h,a,r,g,e,d, ,a,n,d, ,i,n,t,e,r,c,o,o,l,e,d, ,D,O,H,C, ,1,6,-,v,a,l,v,e, ,i,n,l,i,n,e,-,4, ,a,l,u,m,i,n,u,m, ,b,l,o,c,k, ,a,n,d, ,h,e,a,d, ,d,i,r,e,c,t, ,f,u,e,l, ,i,n,j,e,c,t,i,o,n,,D,i,s,p,l,a,c,e,m,e,n,t,:,1,3,8, ,c,u, ,i,n, ,2,2,6,1, ,c,c,P,o,w,e,r,:,3,1,0, ,h,p, ,@, ,5,5,0,0, ,r,p,m,T,o,r,q,u,e,:,3,5,0, ,l,b,-,f,t, ,@, ,3,0,0,0, ,r,p,m,,T,R,A,N,S,M,I,S,S,I,O,N,:,...

S,p,e,c,i,f,i,c,a,t,i,o,n,s, ,2,0,1,8, ,F,o,r,d, ,M,u,s,t,a,n,g, ,E,c,o,B,o,o,s,t, ...

S,p,e,c,i,f,i,c,a,t,i,o,n,s, ,2,0,1,8, ,F,o,r,d, ,M,u,s,t,a,n,g, ,E,c,o,B,o,o,s,t, ...

#Continues for infinite rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas:

```
import re
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

URL = requests.get('https://www.caranddriver.com/reviews/a24847025/2018-ford-mustang-automatic-transmission-performance/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(URL.text, 'html.parser')

#Create a file to write to, add headers row 
csv.writer(open('CarScrapeTest.csv','a',newline='\n'))

for tag in soup.find_all(class_="specs-content"):
    DataList=pd.Series(tag.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n".replace('"', "")).split())
df.to_excel('CarScrapeTest.xlsx', sheet_name='Car&Driver')
    
df = pd.DataFrame(DataList).transpose()
```

This gives an excel file with a zero in the first column and counting up from zero in the first row. But all the strings are in one row and everywhere there is a space in the string is separated by another column.